# What is a street sign in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary

It recently occurred to me that I don't know what to call a street sign in Latin.
I know that a general word for "sign" is *signum*, but the dictionaries I consulted do not specify whether it applies to this kind of use as well.
Perhaps a better English keyword is "plaque" than "sign", but at least Lewis and Short appear not to use this word.

So, what would be a good word for a street sign in Latin?
Are there attestations of this use or something similar enough?

Comment: Which dictionaries did you consult? Did you check the Vatican lexicon or Ephemeris?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Finnish dictionaries and L&S, neither of the two you mentioned. I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: There is at least one street name mentioned in Actus Apostolorum 9:11: the Straight street (vicus qui vocatur Rectus). According to EN wikipedia this was "the old decumanus maximus, the main Roman road, of Damascus". So I doubt if it would have needed a street sign, being known well enough.

Comment: @JobRozemond Ancient Rome had a number of named roads too, including the famous Via Appia. I'm not sure if they had signs or what they were called, though.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Have you heard of the Tabula Peutingeriana? Finnish wikipedia has a scrollable version, and the English wikipedia has a cut-out of Rome, showing the roads and their names.

Comment: As we can see in Pompey, the Romans certainly had signs designating the number of the regio and insula. https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=JqxTpdgZ&id=0884F7416FFBE745FA2EA04073CF25AC5C5CFCCC&thid=OIP.JqxTpdgZrsK5bpKlayUebgHaFj&mediaurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2F08%2F35%2F34%2F08353418de7dfa3321f231564559534a.jpg&exph=852&expw=1136&q=pompeii+street+signs&simid=608029265035725095&ck=5B76A2DAFBD1A5CCEFDF9F8A46066261&selectedindex=3&form=IRPRST&idpp=overlayview&ajaxhist=0&vt=0&sim=11

Comment: @fdb Do you happen to know what the Romans called these signs? I expected them to have had them but I recall no word associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

Who knows, but here's how Avellanus deals with it in *Arena Palaestrarum* (Tentamen XI, p. 45): ”Sunt enim viarum plúrimae, ubi nec lámpades compitales nómina viarum ferant, nec domus angulares ulla nómina aut inscriptiones exhibeant.“ I think it's fairly safe to assume that Avellanus would have used The Word if he knew It. How about *titulus*?